# Передача функции по параметру и возврат значения

Tags: php, массивы, функции, циклы

Добрый день. Я новичок в php и поэтому уже сломал голову в понимании того, почему этот код не работает как надо.
Есть 2 функции. Первая - это рекурсивный прогон по массиву, в которую мы передаем массив и вторую функцию, а вторая сравнивает значение на соответствие и возвращает 1 или 0.

```
function trace($arr, $func) {
  foreach ($arr as $el) {
      if (is_array($el)) {
          trace($el, $func);
      } else {
           print_r($el);
           $bff = $func($el);
           var_dump($bff);
           if ($bff) {
              return $bff;
           }
      }
  }
}
function sizeFlag($el) {
    if ($el >= 120) {
        return  1;
    } else {
       return 0;
    }
}
$bigFrameFlag = trace($modules, 'sizeFlag');
var_dump ($bigFrameFlag);
```

И сам массив:

```
$modules= array(
    array(
        'w' => 70,
        'h' => 60
    ),
    array(
        'w' => 80,
        'h' => 120
    ),
    array(
        'w' => 80,
        'h' => 120
    )
);
```

выводит - >

```
70 int(0) 60 int(0) 80 int(0) 120 int(1) 80 int(0) 120 int(1) 
NULL
```

Не пойму почему на первом значении 120 код не прерывается и почему `$bigFrameFlag = NULL`.

Comment: Эта строка `trace($el, $func);` ничего не возвращает. Может надо `return trace($el, $func);`?

Comment: код не прерывается потому что вы завершаете только текущий рекурсиный вызов, на одном уровне. Собственно, для массива такой структуры каков- смысл в рекурсии?

Answer (score 0):

ну 2 return'а там явно ни к чему, но я в принципе уже разобрался. первый else же не выполняется, а цепочка которая выполняется потом по рекурсии возвращает значение но никуда его не записывает. нужен просто счетчик, который будет прерывать цикл, при значении               `$counter = trace($el, $func);` true
p.s. тем более если просто поставить return как посоветовали, то он на второй итерации просто остановится.

Answer (score 0):

Я только не понял что такое bigFrameFlag что именно нужно вернуть?

```
<?php
$modules= array(
    array(
        'w' => 70,
        'h' => 60
    ),
    array(
        'w' => 80,
        'h' => 120
    ),
    array(
        'w' => 80,
        'h' => 120
    )
);

function trace($arr, $func) {
  foreach ($arr as $el) {
      if (is_array($el)) {
         if (trace($el, $func)) return; // <----- чтобы вернулось но что?
      } else {
           print_r($el);
           $bff = $func($el);
           var_dump($bff);
           if ($bff) {
              return $bff;
           }
      }
  }
}
function sizeFlag($el) {
    return $el >= 120 ? 1 : 0; // <--- упрощение кода
}

$bigFrameFlag = trace($modules, 'sizeFlag');
var_dump ($bigFrameFlag); 

?>
```

Comment: ваше упрощение кода можно упростить до `return $el >= 120`

Comment: нельзя тогда вывод будет другим

Comment: а в `return` очевидно, обычно пишут, то что получено с предыдущего вызова.

Comment: и каким же он будет вдруг?

Comment: 70bool(false)
60bool(false)
80bool(false)
120bool(true)

Comment: я не знаю важно это или нет но предпочитаю сохранять идентичность при упрощении кода

Comment: и чего? это как то на логику влияет? `+$func(...)` можете написать, чтобы к целому привести. но сути для автора это не изменит.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119807/discussion-between-daniil-loban-and-teran).